# Are there contemporary adherents to this view about systemised ethics?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, metaethics, rationality

> [In  some parts of the field](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdfplus/10.1086/intejethi.18.3.2376640) of  truth,  no  doubt,  men  who work
>   by these divergent  ways are  apt  as  men  to  represent 
>   antithetical  types.  But  over the whole  field  this need not be 
>   so,  for  in  some  parts  of it the main  work  of  systematization 
>   is just  to  cut away obstructions  from in-  tuition.  This is  the 
>   case  in ethics.  Systematic  work  in  that  department  is,  as  I 
>   conceive  it,  almost  wholly  negative;  its  business  is  just
>   this,  to break  down  those  false systems  which  our irrational 
>   thirst  for  unity  has set  up  and  which,  so  long  as they hold
>   the field, blur and obscure  insight.  Positive  con-  struction  in 
>   ethics  is insight  and  little  else.  Here  poet and  philosopher 
>   meet;  and that  is why Nietzsche,  musician  and  artist to the core
>   as he  is,  is  nevertheless  a  philosopher  also.

Are there contemporary adherents to this view, either in ethics or Nietzsche studies? I guess I'm frustrated with ethics but still feel I know right from wrong: it could be an easy way out!

Answer (score 1):

Great quote!  I would haste to add clarification that "these divergent fields" are poetry and philosophy, specifically, and that the author is A. C. Pigou.

I don't think the quote makes any particularly novel statement and I suppose that most people would naturally agree once they considered what the author was doing.  How can any person be held to an ethical requirement that we know is paradoxical?  (negative work in ethics)

In my thinking, ethics is anchored pretty well by "the golden rule": "do to others what you would have them do to you."  This, in turn, is a good idea because of (let's call it) "the golden premise": "others are as valuable as me, or maybe more valuable".

Is "the golden premise" available without intuition, i.e. through logic alone?  I suspect not.  So Pigou's assertion seems perfectly fine.

Comment: but is it available through insight alone, without logic? is it *only* available when we have given up on or negated all systematic reasoning about ethics?

Comment: @confused, my "golden premise", I suspect, is available prior to any action of logic.  But that is not to say by any means that it disappears under the light of logic, like charm does in the Keats poem quoted by Pigou ( https://www.bartleby.com/126/37.html ).

Comment: I would say that my "golden premise" fits well as that thing identified by Gödel's incompleteness theorem (which says that no system can ever be complete) as necessary for ethics in spite of being outside of ethics.

Answer (score 0):

The quote seems to be suggesting that the formalisation of ethics is all about identifying false (or logically flawed) systems by analysis. This seems correct.

Metaphysics, of which ethics is a part, is all about refuting theories to reveal those that survive analysis. Logic cannot prove truth but can be used to guard against error.

So he makes the point that analysis will dispose of incoherent theories, a negative process, while for a positive theory we would need intuition and insight.

'Contemporary adherents' of this view would seem to include just about everyone. It is well-understood that metaphysics does not produce a positive result. The situation is much the same in physics where we can falsify theories but never prove they are 'true'.

Comment: do you mean that just about everyone believes that moral knowledge cannot be expressed in a moral system? seems unlikely to me, but i'm not sure

Comment: @confused.- Oh no, I'm a big fan of systematic ethics and metaphysics.but logic cannot create an ethical system. It has to be an act of intuition and insight that extrapolates from logic. Such a system may be tested in logic but only once it has been created. Another way to say this is that logical results have to be interpreted, and this interpretation requires insight and imagination. Logic can only refute an ethical theory, never verify its truth.

Comment: but surely interpretation can involve both insight / imagination AND building a positive system.

Comment: @confused - I'd say so, yes. But a 'system' requires logical consistency as a basic property. In reality we have to use logic. imagination and intuition all at the same time, as we do in physics for the interpretation of data and when forming hypotheses to test, but logic would rule as formal consistency is the most basic requirement for a 'reasonable' theory. Just my view, of course.

Comment: @PeterJ The comparison to physics is interesting.  Physicists create theories that are subject to falsification, and once they've been adequately pounded on use them.  The purpose is to learn the truth as best we can.  The original quote says that the construction of ethics is based on insight and little else, which would seem to translate into physics being based on intuition and little else.

Comment: @DavidThornley - Quite so, but I'm not endorsing the idea that ethics is based only on insight. I would argue it should be based on data, logic and analysis.supported by imagination and insight. All of them seem necessary.